# Set time out and clear time out with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can make this function `getUsers` call every 5 seconds? it should wait for the ajax call to complete and then start it again till ajax returns empty.

```
        var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function getUsers(){
var dbBatchSize = 1000;
var startIndex = 10000;
var exit = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: '" . Yii::app()->createUrl('/Search/GetListOfUsers/') . "',
        data:'startIndex='+startIndex+'&dbBatchSize='+dbBatchSize,
        type:\"POST\",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('polling');
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

}

When ajax returns `data.length == 4` this set time out function should stop

```
if (data.length == 4) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to wait for ajax complete, I prefer you use setTimeout on success. Also, there is no repeated call set in your code above.

You might need to use setInterval for repeat execution.

```
function getUsers() {
  var dbBatchSize = 1000;
  var startIndex = 10000;
  var exit = false;

  $.ajax({
    url: '" . Yii::app()->createUrl(' / Search / GetListOfUsers / ') . "',
    data: 'startIndex=' + startIndex + '&dbBatchSize=' + dbBatchSize,
    type: \ "POST\",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.length != 4) {
        setTimeout(getUsers, 5000); //repeat execution
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clearTimeout`

```
success: function (data) {
        if (data.length == 4) 
            clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
```